# np.where function: can it only retrieve values from specific columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocT4G.png)I am using the np.where() function to retrieve accuracy values in certain conditions of an experiment. I have a data frame with lots of columns, including an accuracy one (titled 'correct') and a reaction times one (titled 'reactiontime'). I have retrieved accuracy data fine using the function; my code was:

```
df['acc1_eyeheight_f'] = np.where((df.metadata == 'eyeheight_f') & (df.frontal_1.str.contains("1")) | (df.frontal_2.str.contains("1")), df.correct, np.NaN) #if metadata had the condition, return the corresponding correct value

acc1_eyeheight_f= df.groupby('participant_private_id').mean()['acc1_eyeheight_f']  

print(acc1_eyeheight_f)
```

but when I try to do the exact same, but with retrieving the reaction time data via:

```
df['rt1_eyeheight_f'] = np.where((df.metadata == 'eyeheight_f') & (df.frontal_1.str.contains("1")) | (df.frontal_2.str.contains("1")), df.reactiontime, np.NaN) #if metadata had the condition, return the corresponding correct value

rt1_eyeheight_f= df.groupby('participant_private_id').mean()['rt1_eyeheight_f']  

print(rt1_eyeheight_f)
```

I get a key error for 'rt1_eyeheight_f'. When I do print(df), the column does exist and there are no spaces in the wrong place.

I was wondering if it is anything to do with the values inside the cell?

Thanks in advance - I am very confused!

[[image: here is dome of the data]]

Comment: `where` doesn't do anything special.  It just uses the arrays and values that you provide as arguments.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). Also please include enough of `df.head()` as part of your [mcve].

Comment: Maybe split that line to two lines: make the groupby and assign it to a name; then extract the column and assign it to a different name. Then you can inspect the groupby, maybe post some minimal example of the groupby's.

Comment: Can you share a few rows of data?

Comment: I have added some of the data - thanks.